# Jquery animate loop only last element

Tags: jquery, foreach, jquery-animate

I use jquery `$("#" + theidoftheelement).animate(...)` in a foreach loop in order to animate one element after the other but only the last animation works... 
Plase help!

edit:
more code:(txt is smome text from a file)

```
 txt.forEach(function (lcb) {
                    lcb = lcb.split("   ", 30);

                    var header = document.createElement('h3');
                    header.id = 'Infralist_' + lcb[2];
                    header.className = 'Infraa';
                    header.textContent = lcb[2];
                    document.getElementById("MainContent_Infralist").appendChild(header);

                    $('#' + lcb[2]).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 500);

                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetWidth);
                initlist(runstr);};`
```

Comment: Do you start them at the same time? please post more code also

Comment: Are you trying to select multiple elements with the same ID? IDs must be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the foreach loop?

Comment: I think it's a timing issue; can you post your code and/or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: in a for loop they are not fired at the same time...
but should i add perhaps a delay?

Comment: @nullability no, the id changes each time

Comment: @AlexMorrise here's the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now:

```
var runningvar =-1;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
                    ++runningvar;
                    if (runningvar >= txt.length) {
                        interval = null;
                    }
                    var lcb = txt[runningvar];
                    lcb = lcb.split("   ", 30);

                    var header = document.createElement('h3');
                    header.id = 'Infralist_' + lcb[2];
                    header.className = 'Infraa';
                    header.textContent = lcb[2];
                    document.getElementById("MainContent_Infralist").appendChild(header);

                   document.getElementById("Infralist_" + lcb[2]).style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("Infralist_" + lcb[2]).style.opacity = "1";
                    $('#' + "Infralist_" + lcb[2])

                        .hide()
                        .fadeIn(500, function () { });

                    ///////
                }, 500);
```

Jquery doesn't seem to be able to override css properties so I set all to visible and then hid it again with jquery - and then faded it in (and I added an Interval)

edit: actually this didn't work they all were displayed, but again only the last animated, but now it works: I replaced this `$('#' + "Infralist_" + lcb[2])` by this `$(document.getElementById("Infralist_" + lcb[2]))`

Answer (score 0):

Run your animate loop using a `setTimeout` like for each iteration.

Code:

```
$("#animator").click(function () {
    $('.demo').each(function (index) {
        var self = this
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(self).animate({
                opacity: 0.25,
                left: "+=50",
                height: "toggle"
            });
        }, index * 500);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/XFJXd/

Comment: For me without timeout not work, all the animations fire at the same time

Comment: Yep, but they ALL are fired... in my code its only the last one